# I want to do post request every 3 seconds to http://localhost:8080/markable/messages in the following springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

These are the files I developed , However I am still unable to implement the above said post. please advise me where I am going wrong.My code works fine with postman and springboot tomcat, However I want to automate the post to /messages url.

**MessageController.java**

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import service.MessageService;
import model.Message;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/markable")
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired 
    MessageService ms;

    @RequestMapping(value="/messages", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public HttpStatus takeInput(@RequestBody Message input) {
        boolean flag=ms.addMissionId(input.getMissionId());
        System.out.println(flag);

        if(flag)
            return HttpStatus.CREATED;
        else 
            return HttpStatus.CONFLICT;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/messages/all")
    public HashSet<Integer> getAll() {
        return ms.getAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/messages/{id}")
    public int getMissionId(@PathVariable("id") String id)
    {
        int inputId = Integer.parseInt(id);
        return ms.getMissionId(inputId);
    }
}
```

**FixedMessagePoster.java**

```
package poster;
import model.Message;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Component
public class FixedRateMessagePoster {

    Message m;
    int count=0;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate=3000)
    public void doPost()
    {
        try {
            m=new Message();
            m.setMissionId(count);
            count++;
            int seed = 1000+(int)(Math.random()*(20000-1000) +1);
            m.setSeed(seed);

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
            String uri = new String("http://localhost:8080/markable/messages");

            restTemplate.postForLocation(uri,m);

            System.out.println("hello");
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**MessageService.java**

```
package service;

import java.util.HashSet;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import model.Message;
import controller.MessageController;

@Service
public class MessageService {

    static HashSet<Integer> missionIds = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public HashSet<Integer> getAll(){
        return missionIds;
    }

    public boolean addMissionId(int missionId) {
        return missionIds.add(missionId);
    }

    public int getMissionId(int id){
        if(missionIds.contains(id))
            return id;
        else 
            return -1;
    }
}
```

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Markable</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Application for Markable</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spring.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>gs-scheduling-tasks</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your code's very hard to read as it's in one big block. Could you reformat your question and break it up? Also, I didn't see your main class in there. Sharing a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: My idea is to hit the /messages url with a post request every n seconds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things which look really odd.

1. Why are you importing something of a getting started project on spring? This does not make sense at all.
2. Since your question is missing your Application class, double check that you added the `@EnableScheduling` annotation.
3. Why are you calling a rest controller in your own app through a `RestTemplate`?  In essence you could inject the message service directly in your `FixedMessagePoster` and add these calls every x seconds.
4. If you'd create your `RestTemplate` as a bean (`@Bean` in your application or a configuration class) you wouldn't have to add all the `MessageConverter`s with every call.
5. Its really good practice to add curly braces around if-else even if you could leave then away. That will increase readability.
6. In some classes you are importing `Message` whereas it is nowhere used.
7. Since the message you are posting in your `FixedMessagePoster` is only used locally in the method I'd strongly encourage you to make this also method local and not a member of the class.
8. You should never use `System.out` to output some information. Just use the logger that is build into Spring Boot. (Hint: slf4j and you'll not be dependent on the framework used)
9. Your exception handling is not ideal. Only wrap into a try-catch what is really necessary.